Transition delay not resetting on hover when transition color is same as initial color
Given the codepen - https://codepen.io/jonny-b31/pen/ExzPypw

I created a container with 2 blocks and when i hover on them, i have to update the background accordingly. By default, block 1 color was set.

When i hover out, i wanted to keep the last hovered color. So, as a hack i added transition-delay to look like its preserving the last hover color and on hover im resetting the transition-delay to immedietely switch colors.

However, when im hovering out from block 2 to outside, then going to block 1, the transition-delay is not resetting. My guess is that, when moving outside of container, the color is switching back to default color which is block 1 color and when i move my cursor to block 1, its seeing the same color again and somehow not applying the hover reset delay. But im not able to figure out how to fix it.
Here the sample code and codepen is linked above:


<div class="main">
  <div class="hover-container">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>

.main {
  border: 5px solid teal;
  width: 500px;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
  transition: background 1ms linear;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}
.hover-container {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
.main:has(.block:first-child:hover) {
  transition-delay: 1ms;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main:has(.block:last-child:hover) {
  transition-delay: 1ms;
  background: lightyellow;
}
</style>


The reason seems to be transition-delay is not resetting when we are changing to same color which was initially.Tried some things like adding whole transition property on hover again but no effect.


Are you fixed on a css only solution? I think you might be getting to a level of complexity that would be much more clear in js :)

You could always just add transition: none; to your .main:has(.block:first-child:hover) I believe, but you're awfully close to css not making a ton of sense here.

@asyncawait, yeah js solution seems easy to understand than this. adding an active class on mouseover but i was fixated on css only solution and this seems to work. Also thanks, adding 'none' transition worked :) but not sure why it wasn't working with delay.

Here's an example of accomplishing your design with js, considering the transition: none; worked for your css only transition.


const get = query => document.querySelector(query);

const container = get(".hover-container");

get(".block:first-child").addEventListener(
  "mouseenter", 
  () => container.style.background = "lightgreen"
);

get(".block:last-child").addEventListener(
  "mouseenter", 
  () => container.style.background = "lightyellow"
);
.main {
  border: 5px solid teal;
  aspect-ratio: 2 / 1;
  position: relative;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.hover-container {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="hover-container">
    <div class="block">1</div>
    <div class="block">2</div>
  </div>
</div>




Yup thanks. I wonder which one will be better performance wise considering i'll have to make 8-10 blocks and on hover of each, have to change background image. The one benefit i saw from css was i was able to load all background images using
background-image: var(--selection-1-img), var(--selection-2-img),
var(--selection-3-img), var(--selection-4-img); This would preload all images and on hover change, the images updated instantly.

You can use js to toggle a class and take advantage of all the same css advantages in that case. css might have some advantages in performance when it comes to animations, but in this case js will have broader comparability with browsers and be just as performant.
